# laravel cashier start charging after trial period

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using laravel8 and cashier stripe. I want to charge user only after their trial period which is one month(30 days trial).
In users table I have `trial_expiry` column which include trial expiry date(for example: 2022-06-30).
Lets say my trial will expire in 20 days from now and user want to take one of monthly plan now(eg: business plan). Now I want to charge user only after his trial period even if he subscribes to plan before his trial finish.
I wrote some code below, but I am not sure how to achieve it.

```
      public function upgradeFromTrial(Request $request) {
            $request->user()->newSubscription(
                'default',
                $request->priceId
            )->trialUntil(now()->addMonth())->create($request->token);
      }
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Laravel but you can achieve it by using Stripe API directly.

When creating the subscription, you can set [trial_peroid_days](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=php#create_subscription-trial_period_days) to 20 to start a 20-day trial without payment.

If you want to remind your customer to set up the payment details before the end of the trial period, you can register [customer.subscription.trial_will_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.trial_will_end) in your Webhook endpoint and Stripe will send this event to you three days before the end of the trial.

You can use the client_secret from the subscritpion’s [pending_setup_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent) to render the PaymentElement, and the collected PaymentMethod will be used for the future recurring payments for this subscription.